# Store receives empty data from service

Tags: angular

For a basic store implementation my service tries to load task objects. In `map` the tasks are sorted by their id and in `do` the tasks are dispatched to the store. However, at the store the data is empty (`TypeError: action.data is undefined`). *Why?*

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { LOAD, EDIT, ADD, REMOVE, TaskStore } from '../services/stores/index';
import { Task } from '../domain/task';

@Injectable()
export class TaskService {

  private headers = new HttpHeaders();
  private tasksUrl = 'http://localhost:8090/task/tasks/';

  tasks$: Observable<Task[]>;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private taskStore: TaskStore) {
    this.headers = this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers = this.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

    this.tasks$ = taskStore.items$;
  }

  getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    this.httpClient.get<Task[]>(this.tasksUrl).map((result: any) => {
      console.log('fetched ' + result._embedded.tasks.length + ' Tasks from server');
      result._embedded.tasks.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
    }).do((tasks) => {
      this.taskStore.dispatch({ type: LOAD, data: tasks });
    });

    return this.tasks$;
  }

}
```

The store:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Task } from '../../models/model-interfaces';

export const LOAD = 'LOAD';
export const ADD = 'ADD';
export const EDIT = 'EDIT';
export const REMOVE = 'REMOVE';

export class TaskStore {
  private tasks: Task[] = [];
  items$ = new BehaviorSubject<Task[]>([]);

  dispatch(action) {
    console.log("dispatched")
    this.tasks = this._reduce(this.tasks, action);
    this.items$.next(this.tasks);
  }

  _reduce(tasks: Task[], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case LOAD:
        return [...action.data];
      case ADD:
        return [...tasks, action.data];
      case EDIT:
        return tasks.map(task => {
          const editedTask = action.data;
          if (task.id !== editedTask.id) {
            return task;
          }
          return editedTask;
        });
      case REMOVE:
        return tasks.filter(task => task.id !== action.data.id);
      default:
        return tasks;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is this.tasks$ inside getTasks() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution works as follows. In the TaskListComponent a list of tasks is displayed (`*ngFor="let task of tasks$ | async"`). It subscribes/destroys the subscription on the `items$`-BehaviorSubject of the store (for the store see the original post). In the ngOnInit of the TaskListComponent the service is called to fetch the tasks from the server. As soon as the service receives them they are sent to the taskStore which does a dispatch and sends the data (`this.items$.next(this.tasks)`) to the subscribed observers of the BehaviorSubject.

TaskListComponent

```
tasks$: Observable<Task[]>;

constructor(private taskService: TaskService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.tasks$ = this.taskService.tasks$;
  this.taskService.getTasks();
}
```

TaskService

```
tasks$: Observable<Task[]>;

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private taskStore: TaskStore) {
  this.tasks$ = taskStore.items$;
}

getTasks() {
    this.httpClient.get<Task[]>(TASKS_URL).map((result: any) => {
      return result._embedded.tasks.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
    }).subscribe((tasks) => {
      this.taskStore.dispatch({type: LOAD, data: tasks});
    });
  }
```

Don't know why the original post was downrated. If I can add something to make it more clear and help-/useful to others please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform). It is the go to solution for using redux in angular.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. See my post below. Thx for your hint to ngrx. Will try that asap as well.